Does a tensor product change when replacing $R$ with $R/I$?
I'm trying to prove the following module isomorphism:
Let $M$, $N$ be two $\newcommand\quotient[2]{{^{\Large #1}}/{_{ \Large #2}}} \quotient{R}{I}$-modules. By restriction of scalars, these $\quotient{R}{I}$-modules also carry $R$-module structures. I want to show the following isomorphism:
$$
{_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N \cong {_R} \left( M \otimes_{\quotient{R}{I}} N \right)
$$

An isomorphism as $R$ modules, presumably?

For $M \otimes_{R/I} N$ to make sense, $M$ and $N$ need to be $R/I$-modules in the first place.

Even if both are modules over $R/I$, the tensor products might not be isomorphic even as abelian groups, leave alone as more complicated structures.

OP should clarify, but I expect that the intent of the question is that the $R$-module structures are obtained by "restriction of scalars" (with a suitable expansion of what "restriction" means), i.e., by composing the given module structure $R/I \to \hom(N, N)$ with the ring map $R \to R/I$ to get an induced $R$-module structure.

@Arthur Yes, the isomorphism being asked is an isomorphism as $R$-modules.

@Mark Actually, the claimed statement is correct.

I'll take the liberty of answering what I suspect is being asked. Suppose given a ring $R$ (not necessarily commutative) and a two-sided ideal $I$, and suppose given a right $R/I$-module $M$ and a left $R/I$-module $N$. Define a left $R$-module structure on $N$ by composing evident ring maps
$$R \overset{\phi}{\to} R/I \to \hom(N, N)$$
where $\phi: R \to R/I$ is the ring quotient map, or in other words by defining $r \cdot n := \phi(r)n$, and similarly define a right $R$-module structure on $M$ by $m \cdot r := m \phi(r)$. Is it true that
$$M \otimes_{R/I} N \cong M \otimes_R N$$
as abelian groups?
The question could be asked even a little more precisely, but I'll weave that into an answer. The answer is 'yes'. If $\otimes$ denotes the tensor product for abelian groups, then $M \otimes_R N$ can be constructed as a coequalizer of maps of the form
$$M \otimes R \otimes N \underset{1_M \otimes \lambda}{\overset{\rho \otimes 1_N}{\rightrightarrows}} M \otimes N$$
where $\rho$ denotes the right $R$-action on $M$ and $\lambda$ denotes the left action on $N$. (In case the terminology is unfamiliar, a coequalizer of two maps $f, g$ between abelian groups can be defined as the cokernel of $f - g$). The ring map $\phi: R \to R/I$ induces a map from this diagram to the similarly formed diagram
$$M \otimes R/I \otimes N \underset{1_M \otimes \lambda'}{\overset{\rho' \otimes 1_N}{\rightrightarrows}} M \otimes N.$$
The key point is that for the latter diagram, a map $f: M \otimes N \to P$ to an abelian group $P$ coequalizes the two maps, i.e.,
$$f \circ (\rho' \otimes 1_N) = f \circ (1_M \otimes \lambda'),$$
if and only if it coequalizes the two maps $\rho \otimes 1_N$, $1_M \otimes \lambda$. The "only if" is trivial. The "if" comes from the fact that $\phi$ is a epimorphism between abelian groups, and that tensoring such an epimorphism with an abelian group on either side (here $M$ or $N$) results in a epimorphism. In other words, since
$$(\rho \otimes 1_N) = (\rho' \otimes 1_N) \circ (1_M \otimes \phi \otimes 1_N), \qquad (1_M \otimes \lambda) = (1_M \otimes \lambda') \circ (1_M \otimes \phi \otimes 1_N),$$
we can "cancel" the epimorphism $1_M \otimes \phi \otimes 1_N$ to infer
$$f \circ (\rho \otimes 1_N) = f \circ (1_M \otimes \lambda)\;\;\; \Rightarrow\;\;\; f \circ (\rho' \otimes 1_N) = f \circ (1_M \otimes \lambda').$$
It easily follows now from universal properties that the induced map between the coequalizers,
$$M \otimes_R N \to M \otimes_{R/I} N,$$
is an isomorphism.

Of course, if the OP is assuming commutativity of $R$ and considering $\otimes_R$ as a functor on $R$-modules, then all will go through as above: the induced map $M \otimes_R N \to M \otimes_{R/I} N$ between $R$-modules is again an isomorphism (it suffices to check this at the abelian group level).

I added another answer which tries to do the same argument as you, but working in $R$-modules instead of abelian groups.

In this answer, I assume that $R$ is a commutative ring. The $R$-module structure on ${_R}M$ is given by $r \cdot m = [r]m$ (and analogously for ${_R}N$).
Consider the following map:
$$
\newcommand\quotient[2]{{^{\Large #1}}/{_{ \Large #2}}} \varphi: {_R}M \times {_R}N \to {_R} \left( M \otimes_{\quotient{R}{I}} N \right), \varphi(a, b) \mapsto a \otimes b
$$
This map is clearly additive in each component. Now take $r \in R$. Then we have
$$
\varphi(r \cdot a, b) = \varphi([r]a, b) = [r]a \otimes b = [r](a \otimes b) = [r]\varphi(a, b) = r \cdot \varphi(a, b)
$$
Hence $\varphi$ is $R$-linear in each component, so it is an $R$-bilinear map of $R$-modules. So we obtain a map
$$
\tilde{\varphi}: {_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N \to {_R} \left( M \otimes_{\quotient{R}{I}} N \right)
$$
with $\tilde{\varphi}(a \otimes b) = a \otimes b$.
On the other hand, we will now endow ${_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N$ with an $\quotient{R}{I}$-module structure and call the resulting module $P$. This is done essentially in the obvious way. For the precise construction, see below.
Now consider the map
$$
\psi: M \times N \to P, \psi(a, b) = a \otimes b
$$
This is an $\quotient{R}{I}$-bilinear map of $\quotient{R}{I}$-modules. So we obtain a map
$$
\tilde{\psi}: M \otimes_{\quotient{R}{I}} N \to P
$$
with $\tilde{\psi}(a \otimes b) = a \otimes b$. But now we can consider the induced map on $R$-modules
$$
{_R}\tilde{\psi}: {_R} \left( M \otimes_{\quotient{R}{I}} N \right) \to {_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N
$$
And it is evident that ${_R}\tilde{\psi} \circ \tilde{\varphi} = \operatorname{id}$ and $\tilde{\varphi} \circ {_R}\tilde{\psi} = \operatorname{id}$. Hence
$$
{_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N \cong {_R} \left( M \otimes_{\quotient{R}{I}} N \right)
$$
as $R$-modules.

Here is the construction of $P$: Given any $[r] \in \quotient{R}{I}$, define
$$
\lambda_{[r]}: {_R}M \times {_R}N \to {_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N, \lambda_{[r]}(a, b) = [r]a \otimes b
$$
This is indeed $R$-linear, because for $s, t \in R$, we have
$$
\lambda_{[r]}(s \cdot a, b) = \lambda_{[r]}([s]a, b) = [r][s]a \otimes b = [s][r]a \otimes b = (s \cdot [r]a) \otimes b = s \cdot ([r]a \otimes b) = s \cdot \lambda_{[r]}(a, b)
$$
and
$$
\lambda_{[r]}(a, t \cdot b) = [r]a \otimes (t \cdot b) = t \cdot ([r]a \otimes b) = t \cdot \lambda_{[r]}(a, b)
$$
Hence $\lambda_{[r]}$ is $R$-bilinear, so we obtain a map
$$
\tilde{\lambda}_{[r]}: {_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N \to {_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N
$$
with $\tilde{\lambda}_{[r]}(a \otimes b) = [r]a \otimes b$. But now the map
$$
\quotient{R}{I} \to \operatorname{End}_R({_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N), [r] \mapsto \tilde{\lambda}_{[r]}
$$
is a ring homomorphism, so it defines the structure of an $\quotient{R}{I}$-module on ${_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N$. We will call the resulting $\quotient{R}{I}$-module $P$.

In the proof that $\varphi$ is bilinear you need to write $r$, not $[r]$. The definition of the R/I module structure is insufficient. I think it's a good exercise to find out why.

But is it $R$-linear in the second component (with argument $b$)? Also, in order to speak of $M \otimes_{R/I} N$, $M$ must start off life as a right module.

With set theoretic foundations, there is no need to introduce $P$ notation, or to distinguish between $\tilde \psi$ and an "induced" map, which is the same function on the same underlying set.

@MartinBrandenburg Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the proof of bilinearity of $\varphi$ by distinguishing when I use the induced $R$-module structure and when I use the $R/I$-module structure.

@MartinBrandenburg I really don't understand why my definition of the $R/I$-module structure on $P$ is insufficient. As far as I understand, I need to check two things: (1.) My scalar multiplication is actually well-defined, i.e. does not depend on a choice of representatives, which follows immediately from the fact that $M$ is an $R/I$-module. (2.) The module axioms, i.e. left- and right-distributivity, associativity and multiplication by the unit, which should all follow immediately. Can you elaborate a bit more about what the issue here is?

@user43208 Sorry, I should've said explicitly that I assume my ring to be commutative here. So the left/right distinction is not important, and the $R$-linearity in the second component is proven exactly analogously to the $R$-linearity in the first component.

@Ben I'm not quite sure that that's true. Even though $M$ and ${_R}M$ have the same set of elements, they carry different scalar multiplications from different rings, so they are distinct objects, even with set-theoretic foundations. I think that we also need to give $P$ its own name, because it's a module over a different ring. And I suppose you're right that $\tilde{\psi}$ and ${_R}\tilde{\psi}$ are the same maps on elements, so set-theoretically identical, but in this answer I wanted to be as explicit as possible, so I didn't want to confuse maps of $R$-modules with maps of $R/I$-modules.

@Smiley1000 Given $x=\sum a_i\otimes b_i$ and $r,r'\in[r]$, you must show $rx = r'x$ for the action to be well defined

Don't do that. Use the universal property (and nothing else). But yes the issue is that not every element is a pure tensor.

@MartinBrandenburg Thank you very much for pointing this out. Using the universal property, I think I gave a correct construction of $P$ now.

In this answer, I assume that $R$ is a commutative ring.
This answer is based on the answer by @user43208 , but doing everything as $R$-modules instead of as abelian groups. We want to show that
$$
\newcommand\quotient[2]{{^{\Large #1}}/{_{ \Large #2}}} {_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N \cong {_R} \left( M \otimes_{\quotient{R}{I}} N \right)
$$
as $R$-modules.
We can consider the two maps
$$
\mu_M: \quotient{R}{I} \otimes_R {_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N \to {_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N, \\
[a], m, n \mapsto am \otimes n
$$
and
$$
\mu_N: \quotient{R}{I} \otimes_R {_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N \to {_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N, \\
[a], m, n \mapsto m \otimes an
$$
Now the tensor product ${_R} \left( M \otimes_{\quotient{R}{I}} N \right)$ can be seen as the coequalizer of the two maps $\mu_M$ and $\mu_N$. However, both maps clearly agree, so the map to the coequalizer is an isomorphism. Hence
$$
{_R}M \otimes_R {_R}N \cong {_R} \left( M \otimes_{\quotient{R}{I}} N \right)
$$
as $R$-modules.

Let $A$ be any ring, $R=A[X]$ and $I=(X)$ so that $R/I\simeq A$.
Also let $M=N=A[X]$ which are $A$- and $R$-modules.
In $M\otimes_RN$ one has $1\otimes X=X\otimes 1$ whereas in $M\otimes_A N$ one has $1\otimes X\neq X\otimes 1$.
(there may be much simpler examples)

I really think you're misinterpreting the intent of the question. I think OP means for the $R$-module structure to be induced from the $R/I$-module structure by "restriction of scalars", viz., via composition $R \to R/I \to \hom(N, N)$ (where $N$ is a left $R/I$-module). What OP wants is true.

@user43208: well, wouldn't that be asking if $(M\otimes_R N)\otimes_RR/I\simeq M\otimes_{R/I}N$ (which is something quite different than what the OP wrote)?

No, I don't think it's asking quite the same, since tensoring with $R/I$ is left adjoint to the restriction along scalars map. He/she is asking about something much simpler, if I understand the intent of the question.

I think also that $R$ is not assumed commutative, so the tensor of a right module with a left module will just be an abelian group.

This is not a counterexample to the claim. Your $M$ and $N$ are not $R/I$-modules, which is what is assumed here.
